# How to get the value of inner attribute of an li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in Java script from which i have to need get the value on an inner attribute of `<li>`.

```
<li class="selected" data-val="1">
```

I have get the tag using

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
```

it is providing me `<li>` whole tag that is fine. But i have to need get the value of data-val attribute (which is within the `<li>`) that is 1.
  How can i get the value of data-val using variable a that is defined. 
  Please explain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a is a collection object so you need to get the element reference using index then use .getAttribute() to get the attribute value()

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
var val = a? a[0].getAttribute('data-val') : '';
//another option for modern browsers
// val = a[0].dataset.val
```

Since you have jQuery, you can use jQuery to select the element and then use data api like

```
var val = $('.selected').data('val')
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use `$(a).attr("data-val")`.

Without jQuery you can use `a.getAttribute("data-val")`

Comment: With jQuery, you can use `$('.selected').data('val')`, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
var dataValValue = $(".selected").attr("data-val");
```

It will get data-val attribute from *first* li from all li with class .selected

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, using jQuery and the first returned element in `a`:

```
$.data(a[0],"val");
$(a[0]).data("val");
```

<strike>Both are equivalent.</strike> Sorry, they're not equivalent, since the first one is lower level, and [does not process `data-*` attributes by itself](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#jQuery-data-element).

There's no need to use `.attr()` since `data-*` attributes are processed automatically in the case of the second one.